# Copy a particular column from multiple excel files to a single column of another excel file

Tags: vbscript

I am failrly new to VBScript, I want to copy a particular column (say Column C) from multiple excel sheets (Source_1.xlsx, Source_2.xlsx, and Source_3.xlsx). and paste it to Column A of another excel sheet Dest.xlsx. This column should be free from duplicate values. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create the excel object, assuming the files are the same, and you use an increasing integer at the end, you can iterate through each excel object. as you iterate through, you can call upon the same column as a const, and copy to a new filename. When you start to have some code, report back and it can be worked on further

```
for i to x
filename = "scen_"& i & ".xlsx"
copyfilename = "copytohere.xlsx"
'set up the object

    for rowstart to rowend
    'get contents of x column
    'copy contents to copyfilename excel doc
     Loop

loop
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Const xlFilterCopy = 2
Const xlUp = -4162
Const xlDown = -4121

strPathSrc = "C:\Test" ' Source files folder
strMaskSrc = "Source_*.xlsx" ' Source files filter mask
iSheetSrc = 1 ' Sourse sheet index or name
iColSrc = 3 ' Source column index, e. g. 3 for "C"
strPathDst = "C:\Test\Dest.xlsx" ' Destination file
iColDst = 1 ' Destination column index

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkBookDst = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathDst)
Set objSheetTmp = objWorkBookDst.Worksheets.Add
objSheetTmp.Cells(1, iColDst).Value = "TempHeader"
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShellApp.NameSpace(strPathSrc)
Set objItems = objFolder.Items()
objItems.Filter 64 + 128, strMaskSrc
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each objItem In objItems
    Set objWorkBookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objItem.Path)
    Set objSheetSrc = objWorkBookSrc.Sheets(iSheetSrc)
    objSheetSrc.Cells(1, iColSrc).Insert xlDown
    objSheetSrc.Cells(1, iColSrc).Value = "TempHeader"
    Set objRangeSrc = GetRange(iColSrc, objSheetSrc)
    If objRangeSrc.Cells.Count > 1 then
        nNextRow = GetRange(iColDst, objSheetTmp).Rows.Count + 1
        objRangeSrc.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , objSheetTmp.Cells(nNextRow, iColDst), True
        objSheetTmp.Cells(nNextRow, iColDst).Delete xlUp
        Set objRangeTmp = GetRange(iColDst, objSheetTmp)
        Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Worksheets.Add
        objRangeTmp.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , objSheetDst.Cells(1, iColDst), True
        objSheetTmp.Delete
        Set objSheetTmp = objSheetDst
    End If
    objWorkBookSrc.Close
Next
objSheetTmp.Cells(1, iColDst).Delete xlUp
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

Function GetRange(iColumn, objSheet)
    With objSheet
        Set GetRange = .Range(.Cells(1, iColumn), .Cells(.Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, iColumn).End(xlUp).Row, iColumn))
    End With
End Function
```